# How to stop after each command

Tags: powershell

I have a high impact script and I want to confirm each command. The script calls several other scripts.

So it looks like this

```
stop_db
migrate_db
..
update_app
..
```

If I set `$ConfirmPreference = 'low'` I must confirm everything inside the above procedures as well. Is it possible to confirm actions only from the top script the easy way ?

---

EDIT: Ideally, this should be as simple as:

```
Enable-BreakAfterEach
stop_db       #stop here with continue y/n but not inside
migrate_db    #""
..
update_app
..
```

Comment: How about putting [void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true) before/after action, needed to be confirmed?

Comment: Use `$PSDefaultParameterValues` to set the `-Confirm` parameter to `$true` for the functions/cmdlets you want to be prompted for

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381042/powershell-prompt-for-would-you-like-to-continue

But I personally like this way as it's a bit more customisable: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, can you provide a solution for above code ? I don't see how what you say is practical.

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is ShouldProcess. Turn each of your individual scripts into using an advance function using ShouldProcess and set the confirm impact for that function to high. That way you are only prompted once those functions rather than turning your confirm impact down to get prompted by everything. Here's a [couple articles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff677563.aspx) on [using advanced functions/ShouldProcess](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/advanced-functions-part-2-shouldprocess-your-script-cmdlets)

Comment: Yeah, thats what I need, I was just hopping I don't have to change the script to achieve that.